# How to remove last two tabs in the products description?

Tags: html, magento

In a Magento site, on product page, product description section their are five tabs. I want to remove last 2 tabs. It is coming from

```
($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html)
```

code.

So by which way I should remove the tabs, please can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you have not mentioned tabs name that you want to remove

Comment: On product page their are 5 tabs i.e. :- 1)Details 2)Additional Information 3)Product tags 4)Custom tab1 5)custom tab N .I want to remove 4th and 5th ,How should I proceed..

Comment: you are using custom theme ? you need to check in catalog.xml or in local.xml. Check for detailed_info in catalog_product_view handler

Comment: I am using ready theme ,also I checked catalog.xml ,But Exact point not getting clear from where to remove it.

Comment: Check for static blocks or theme configuration in backend

Comment: This might help [magento adding tabs in product detail](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51649/adding-custom-tabs-in-product-detail-page) to know where to look for it.

Comment: @Pankaj:-yes get solved..thanks..